# What are the possible arguments can be passed to the option of -Xclang of the Clang compiler?

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang

I'm using Clang as a front-end of my static analysis tool. I noticed that there is the option `-Xclang` that allows me to manually manage LLVM passes triggered by Clang.

```
-Xclang <arg>           Pass <arg> to the clang compiler
```

I already knew that `-Xclang -disable-llvm-passes` will disable all passes. But I could not find any good documentation describing what are the possible arguments passed to `-Xclang`.

Does anyone know where I can find more information about `-Xclang`?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `clang -cc1 --help` to see the full list of options. I believe these options are technically considered "internal" and may change from one release to the next.